# Creating a shared_ptr of vector in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std

In modern C++ we can initialize a vector like this:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

But if I try creating a smart pointer to a vector, this won't compile:

```
auto v = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>({ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
```

Is there any better alternative than resorting to `push_back`s after creation?

Comment: Why do you want the vector on the heap?  The data in the vector is already in the heap so the size of the vector on the "stack" is pretty minimal.

Comment: There's a private class member `vector` in one class and i expose it to other classes via a getter. So instead of passing it by value, I return a `shared_ptr` to it.

Comment: Then return it by reference.

Comment: You can declare the vector on stack and then in getter function pass a pointer to it, or better pass a reference to it.

Comment: @NathanOliver there could be million reasons to have shared ownership over a vector, this is completely legit question and I do not understand why somebody -1 it

Comment: @Slava I didn't down vote it.  I was just questioning the reason why the OP wanted to do this.  I know there are times where you would want to but in many cases it is not needed.

Comment: In my case, the vector is created outside the class, than passed to it on construction, that's why I don't want to pass it by reference or by value.

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry, part for -1 was not related to you, just did not want to create another comment :)

Comment: Fails for g++ 5.1.0 as well: "error: too many arguments to function ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> std::make_shared(_Args&& ...)",

Comment: Worst thing for gcc it compiles for 2 elements in list, but another constructor is called. Very dangerous, looks like a language defect for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
auto v = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(std::initializer_list<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
```

This is working. Looks like compiler cannot eat {} in make_unique params without direct specification of initializer_list.

Minor edit - used MSVC 2015

Comment: Works great! Strange why the compiler couldn't infer the type.

Comment: @Crossfire That is because a braced-init-list has no type.

Comment: Posting this as comment as the question is closed; you can also do `auto is = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; auto v = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(is);`. `auto` always deduces a `braced-init-list` to be a `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @NathanOliver A braced-init-list is not a `std::initializer_list`. Umh, didn't know that. I believe it but do you have a further link for that?

Comment: @NathanOliver `auto myList = {1, 2, 3, 4};` will have a type and it will be deduced to `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Comment: @Crossfire There are special rules for auto that allow it to deduce a type.  For more on that you can see [this](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/03/if-braced-initializers-have-no-type-why.html) article from Scott Meyers

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi I am having problems finding the standardes but from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization we have *A braced-init-list is not an expression and therefore has no type, e.g. decltype({1,2}) is ill-formed.*.  See the notes section in the link for more

Comment: @Simple But.. wouldn't you pay the cost of constructing `is` followed by copying its contents into the `std::vector` and then the destruction of `is` (recall that while construction/destruction of an int is cheap, that's not necessarily true for arbitrary types....)

Comment: @AndreKostur you would pay that cost anyway.

Comment: @simple Not in c++11.  If it's all in one line, the compiler will be able to take advantage of move semantics to move the contents of the initializer_list instead of copy them.  And is no worse off in C++98.

Comment: @AndreKostur no you can't move from an initializer_list.

Comment: @Simple Yikes.  Hunting around leads me to the definition that the initializer_list only gets you const access to its members.  So move's out.  I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively do it by creating another vector directly in parameter in order to move it:

```
auto v = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int>({ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }));
```

Comment: So you are using a `std::initializer_list` to initialize-construct a `std::vector` which is used to copy-construct a `std::vector` which is wrapped in a `std::shared_ptr`. Strange. Interesting. Legit, though.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi To be picky: move-construct, not copy-construct.

Comment: @zenith C++ is powerful, complex, and complicated. It's not picky but most important to talk about the details. In fact details are what this whole site is about, isn't it? So, thank you!