# std::initializer_list not able to be deduced from <brace-enclosed initializer list>

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class whose constructor takes an `initializer_list`:

```
Foo::Foo(std::initializer_list<Bar*> bars)
```

If I attempt to create an object with a *brace-enclosed initializer list* **directly**, the `initializer_list` is correctly deduced:

```
Foo f ({ &b }); // std::initializer_list<Bar*> correctly deduced
```

However, when trying to do the same **indirectly** (with a variadic function template - in this case `make_unique`), the compiler is unable to deduce  the `initializer_list`:

```
std::make_unique<Foo>({ &b }); // std::initializer_list<Bar*> not deduced
```

**Error output:**

> error: no matching function for call to `‘make_unique(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’`

**Questions:**

- Why is the compiler failing to deduce `{ &b }` as a `initializer_list<Boo*>`?
- Is it possible to use the syntax `std::make_unique<Foo>({ &b })` which I desire?

**Full example below:**

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <memory>

struct Bar
{};

struct Foo
{
    Foo(std::initializer_list<Bar*> bars)
    { }
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;

    // initializer_list able to be deduced from { &b }
    Foo f ({ &b });

    // initializer_list not able to be deduced from { &b }
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> p = std::make_unique<Foo>({ &b });

    (void)f;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that there is no template type deduction in `Foo f ({ &b });`, whereas in `std::make_unique` is.

Comment: As a side note: Use `auto`. The whole point of `make_unique` is to be able to use type deduction. Otherwise it would be simpler to just write `std::unique_ptr<Foo> p(new Foo{ &b });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a shared\_ptr of vector in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769617/creating-a-shared-ptr-of-vector-in-c)

Comment: @Starl1ght a better duplicate would be [Calling initializer_list constructor via make_unique/make_shared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379311/calling-initializer-list-constructor-via-make-unique-make-shared), but Yakk's answer to this question is the best answer out of all 3 questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`make_unique` uses perfect forwarding.

Perfect forwarding is imperfect in the following ways:

- It fails to forward initializer lists
- It converts `NULL` or `0` to an integer, which can then not be passed to a value of pointer type.
- It does not know what type its arguments will be, so you cannot do operations that require knowing their type.  As an example:

  ```
  struct Foo { int x; };
  void some_funcion( Foo, Foo ) {};

  template<class...Args>
  decltype(auto) forwarding( Args&& ... args ) {
    return some_function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  ```

  Calling `some_function( {1}, {2} )` is legal.  It constructs the `Foo`s with `{1}` and `{2}`.

  Calling `forwarding( {1}, {2} )` is not.  It does not know at the time you call `forwarding` that the arguments will be `Foo`s, so it cannot construct it, and it cannot pass the construction-initializer-list through the code (as construction-lists are not variables or expressions).
- If you pass an overloaded function name, which overload cannot be worked out at the point of call.  And a set of overloads is not a value, so you cannot perfect forward it through.
- You cannot pass bitfields through.
- It forces takes a reference to its arguments, even if the forwarded target does not.  This "uses" some static const data in ways that can cause a program to be technically ill-formed.
- A reference to an array of unknown size `T(&)[]` cannot be forwarded.  You can call a function taking a `T*` with it, however.

About half of these were taken from [this comp.std.c++ thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.std.c++/wu4r3CWG-VE/ZFcs2Z1aKuQJ), which I looked for once I remembered there were other issues I couldn't recall off the top of my head.

Comment: do you know if there is any work to resolve these imperfections?

Comment: @SteveLorimer: Generally speaking, no. Many of them have adequate workarounds, such as using `nullptr` to get around #2, and avoiding language arrays and bitfields. The only thing you can do about the braced-init-list problem is to use an explicit type. The ultimate problem that all of these issues are derived from is that the forwarding function does not use the signature of the function it is forwarding to. And nobody has expressed any interest in writing a paper to allow that. Reflection might someday allow transparent forwarding, but that'd be C++20 if ever.

Answer (score 4):

A braced initializer has no type.  When you call `make_unique` it tries to deduce the type and fails.  In this case you have to specify the type when calling like

```
std::make_unique<Foo>(std::initializer_list<Bar*>{ &b });
```

This will create a `std::initializer_list<Bar*>` which the compiler can deduce and it will forward it to `Foo::Foo(std::initializer_list<Bar*> bars)`

The reason `Foo f ({ &b });` works is that the compiler knows of the constructor `Foo(std::initializer_list<Bar*> bars)` and braced initializer list of `B*`s can be implicitly converted to a `std::initializer_list<Bar*>`.  There is not type deduction going on.

Comment: What are the rules for deducing the argument to `Foo` in the first case - `Foo f ({ &b })` - if a braced initializer has no type? That is, how can we go from *no type* to `initializer_list` in the first example?

Comment: @SteveLorimer Just added that into the answer.